# Error :MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to apply spring security to my api using jwt.

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/wolox/securing-applications-with-jwt-spring-boot-da24d3d98f83) to implement security

The error i am getting is:

> io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0

Here is my code:

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.panchmeru_studio.security;

import com.panchmeru_studio.filter.AuthenticationFilter;
import com.panchmeru_studio.filter.AuthorizationFilter;

import com.panchmeru_studio.service.ApplicationUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import static com.panchmeru_studio.constants.SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
   // private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfiguration(ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
       // this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


}
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
package com.panchmeru_studio.filter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import static com.panchmeru_studio.constants.SecurityConstants.*;
import com.panchmeru_studio.entities.ApplicationUser;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(applicationUser.getUsername(),
                            applicationUser.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME);
        Key key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(KEY.getBytes());
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
        String token = Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512).setExpiration(exp).compact();
        res.addHeader("token", token);


    }
}
```

AuthorizationFilter.java

```
package com.panchmeru_studio.filter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.panchmeru_studio.constants.SecurityConstants.*;

public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);

        if (header == null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = authenticate(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
        if (token != null) {
            Claims user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(KEY.getBytes()))
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }else{
                return  null;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SecurityConstants.java

```
public class SecurityConstants {
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users/record";
    public static final String KEY = "q3t6w9z$C&F)J@NcQfTjWnZr4u7x!A%D*G-KaPdSgUkXp2s5v8y/B?E(H+MbQeTh";
    public static final String HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";
    public static final Long EXPIRATION_TIME = 1000L*60*30;
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.panchmeru_studio.controller;

import com.panchmeru_studio.entities.ApplicationUser;
import com.panchmeru_studio.repository.ApplicationUserRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    @Autowired    
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserController(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
                         // BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
       // this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/record")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        applicationUser.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(applicationUser.getPassword()));
        applicationUserRepository.save(applicationUser);
    }
}
```

The header that i am getting from  `request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME)` in `AuthorizationFilter` is
`YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`
and it is failing at `.parseClaimsJws(token)` line in  `private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticate(HttpServletRequest request)` method in `AuthorizationFilter`

I have used same guidelines as told in the link, but i am getting the following error.
I am new to spring security.

Comment: Could you share the exception stack trace also?

Comment: Also share what is printed on token value when you start the authentication process. is it like 'Bearer YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' or just plain string 'YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='

Answer (score 0):

If your generated token looks exactly as you posted, then there's something wrong with generating a JWT. A signed JWT (JWS) should always have the form of a long string with three sections separated with dots. So either check the code which generates the token or the code which constructs the request to the server.

By the way, I think that using JWTs for what you're doing here is a bad practice. If you have one server which handles all your flows (authentication, serving frontends, handling APIs, etc.), then just go with plain old sessions. Don't use JWTs to handle sessions. They are not meant to be used for that. If you plan to have separate servers to handle authentication and APIs / frontends then use a fully-featured Authorization Server (open source, e.g. Keycloak, or free product, e.g. Curity Community Edition). The Authorization Server will be responsible for creating the JWT, so you're sure then you will not mess that up :)

If you decide to stick to JWTs and issuing them yourself then consider switching to an asymmetric signing algorithm. Symmetric signing has some security concerns. You can have a look at [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/) which covers security best practices for working with JWTs.